# Which is the best time prescribed to have a meal for a yogi?

Tags: scripture

Recently, i read a post about diet here. As it was backed up by shastras, according to it, grihasthas eat twice a day while yogis or people in vanaprastha stage used to eat only once.

My question is that which is that time to eat meal for those who eat only once a day.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43443/what-are-the-meal-timings-according-to-smritis

Comment: You may want to edit your title since your question is specific to those who eat once in a day.

Comment: @hanugm it still doesn't answer my question. The question is that yogis eat once a day, but when? They eat at morning, noon or at night? When do they eat

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto check now. The suggested similar question didnt answer my question

Comment: @Rudra check this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29703/647

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto still didnt answer my question. When to eat? All it answered was what to eat

Comment: @Rudra Voted for reopen.