# I'm a Bhumihar Brahmin(18),my father a Kaushik and mother a Bharadwaj by Gotra(Read the body)

Tags: vedas, brahmins, varna, upanayanam, dvija

1. I'm 18, as far as I know the Upanayana has to be done when the child is 8, I'm 18, is it too late for me to go through one?
2. I'm a medical student as of now, and I come from an upper middle class family in India, can I still do my Brahmin/Bhumihar duties to claim my Dwijatva or is it too late?
3. If the answer to the above question is yes, then what would those duties be?

P.S It would be preferable if the answers are provided as per the Rigveda, Mandala 1-7

Comment: Note- Gayatri has been chanted in my family since the last many generations, so I'm not a bandhu and haven't lost my caste yet (I suppose), similarly, my father went through his Upanayana on time, and his father before that, just that they didn't have me go through it, can I still go through?

Comment: Another thing to note is that my family hasn't been performing priestly duties though since the last 4-5 generations and has largely been a martial race, serving in the military as commanders for either local rulers, the British Army, then the Indian Army and continues to be so till date, can I still retain my varna status while performing the martial duties of the descendant of lord Parshuram?

Comment: *"preferable if the answers are provided as per the Rigveda"* - the job of dealing with dharma shastras (rules & regulations) is left mainly to Smritis. You're unlikely to find an answer from there. Any case, shastras fix **maximum** age of upanayana for brahmanas as 16. It is a bit higher for kshatriyas, and slightly even higher for vaishyas - beyond which it loses its potency (mainly because gayatri has to take hold before Kama enters heart i.e. before puberty). You can still undergo it, and if your father chants Gayatri daily as part of sandhya-vandan, you can still catch up.

Comment: as far as daily duties are concerned, see [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21108/4435)

Comment: Since personal advice questions are [off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/asking-for-help-solutions-to-solve-personal-issues-should-be-considered-off-to) as per the site guidelines, but yet since your question is very relevant, I’d request you to edit the question to a more generalised tone for eg. can a person who has crossed 18 years of age get upanayanam done despite the age being 8. Can one still do his duties, and what are those duties. Else the question may be closed. I’m voting to leave the question open since you’ll edit out the personal stuff. Thank you :)