# How should be an ideal day according to our scriptures?

Tags: scripture

I want to know about complete overview of how should one spend a day according to scriptures!(i.e Dincharya)

For E.g At what time one should wake up etc.

Comment: see - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21108/4435

Answer (score 2):

I was also pondering over same question, and stumbled upon this very nice book published by Gita Press named [Nityakarm Pujaprakash](https://book.gitapress.org/product-style-5/gita-press-314/), which describes a typical day right from waking up to sleep and in-between.

[image: Nityakarm Pujaprakash Book - Gita Press]

Author Pt Lalbihari Mishra details about following topics

1. When to wake up and what to do after that
2. Shauch kriya incl Snaan (Morning ablutions)
3. How to dress up
4. How to perform Morning Sandhya: Puja archana and Aarti
5. It also talks about Afternoon and Evening Sandhya.

Please have a look at it's contents. I am sure you'd be impressed by the coverage. Eg, just after waking up in bed, it tells us to pray to Ishwar with shlokas and remember our parents. I'd suggest to explore the book further, but feel free to let me know if you need more details here.
[image: Nityakarm Pujaprakash Book Contents]
[image: Nityakarm Pujaprakash Book Contents]
[image: Nityakarm Pujaprakash Book Contents]

The book is available in [Hindi](https://book.gitapress.org/product-style-5/gita-press-314/), [Telugu](https://book.gitapress.org/product-style-5/gita-press-983/), [Gujarati](https://book.gitapress.org/product-style-5/gita-press-572/) and [Nepali](https://book.gitapress.org/product-style-5/nepali/). It is also available on [Kindle](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07BFVTDKZ/).